# How can I reindex a counter to consecutively increment in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have rows as such:

```
+----+------+-------+
| id | name | order |
+----+------+-------+
|  1 | foo  |     2 |
|  2 | bar  |     4 |
|  3 | jam  |     1 |
|  4 | ban  |     3 |
+----+------+-------+
```

Hypothetically, if I were to delete row `3`, we would have this:

```
+----+------+-------+
| id | name | order |
+----+------+-------+
|  1 | foo  |     2 |
|  2 | bar  |     4 |
|  4 | ban  |     3 |
+----+------+-------+
```

I want to reset the order in the table, so it becomes:

```
+----+------+-------+
| id | name | order |
+----+------+-------+
|  1 | foo  |     1 |
|  2 | bar  |     3 |
|  4 | ban  |     2 |
+----+------+-------+
```

i.e. going up incrementally from 1, whilst not changing the "order".

How can I do this?

Comment: Is the order column unique?

Comment: @GurV Yes, the `order` column is unique.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering the `order` column is unique, you can use user variables with an update join like this:

```
update t t1
join (
    select id,
        @rn := @rn + 1 rn
    from (
        select *
        from t
        order by `order`
        ) t
    cross join (
        select @rn := 0
        ) t2
    ) t2 on t1.id = t2.id

set t1.`order` = t2.rn;
```

Answer (score 1):

Like the answer from GurV, but simpler:

```
SET @rn := 0;

UPDATE MyTable
SET `order` = (@rn:=@rn+1)
ORDER BY `order`;
```

Explanation: initialize a session variable @rn to zero. Run an update for every row in order by `order`, and set the `order` column (I would recommend choosing a column name that is not the same as a keyword, by the way).

The value you set that column to is an expression, which uses variable-assignment syntax so for every row, it increments the variable.

Comment: definitely shorter :) thanks for that - but just one problem I found from just testing it, I'll make the edit now